# Hot Reload during Unit testing

Tags: testing, dart, tdd, flutter

I develop right now a small flutter app. I think as everyone, I fell in love with the hot reload feature.

So now I'm wondering if there is any possibility to have the same developer experience during unit test. Do have to turn a flag somewhere or is it right know just no possible.

If is not possible, are there any plans to make it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess what you want is to run the new tests as soon as they changed. But in that case it's not a hot reload. Simply a watcher that detect whenever your sources or your tests have changed and restart them.

Flutter, and the lower layers, don't implement "watch" yet. Although you can achieve a similar effect quite easily using a node packages

`npm i -g watch` which will install [watch](https://github.com/mikeal/watch) globally so that you can use it in as a command line.

and then in your terminal do

`watch "flutter test" lib test` which will run `flutter test` everytime something change inside lib and test folders

Comment: It would be something of both. Yes, first of all, a watcher would be fine with the same executing speed as the Hot Reload feature. I got my answers. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the unit test as an app to be able to use hot reload.

In IntelliJ you can copy the run configuration for `lib/main.dart` and then select the file `test/my_test.dart` in the copy.

There is no support to run single tests from a set of tests in a test file in IntelliJ (don't know other IDEs) when you run a test this way.

In my opinion, if you run it as unit test, hot reload doesn't bring much benefit anyway because execution is very fast.