# pub run test -p android -> Unknown platform "android". - What Im doing wrong?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-test

Hi I try to write Integration test against my firebase and would love to run them on the device.
When I try to run those test with pub or the flutter command I get the following error.

```
> pub run test -p android test/firebase_test.dart
Unknown platform "android".
```

or with the flutter command

```
> flutter packages pub run test -p android test/firebase_test.dart                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Unknown platform "android".
pub finished with exit code 65
```

What I doing wrong?

firebase_test.dart

```
@TestOn('android')
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
...
```

pubspec.yaml

```
...
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  test: ^1.6.3
  mockito: ^4.1.0

...
```

Comment: Are you sure that you can run unit tests on a device? If you want to run integration tests, you will have to use [`flutter_driver`](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction).

Comment: Not 100% sure but regarding to the documentation of [test platform selectors](https://pub.dev/packages/test#platform-selectors) I'm pretty sure :D.

Comment: So for local testing I did the same thing as mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49004259/hot-reload-during-unit-testing) by Günter